# sequence diagram sub functions

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

Well, I'm working on sequence diagram and I got confused when I found a some function could  be a standalone function for a complete process the user may do, and it could be a sub process of a bigger process like

the first process: "historyClassRegistration(studentId)"
the second process: "allClassesRegistration(studentId)"

the student can register only history class
also he can register all classes which includes "historyClassRegistration" process inside 

the question is:
should I draw the "historyClassRegistration" process alone with it's sub-processes and redraw it again with it's sub-processes in "allClassesRegistration", or what can I do???

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it probably depends on what use case the sequence diagram is trying to demonstrate.
It will also depend on the structure of the system.

If I had control of the design, the first operation would probably not exist.  The type of class being registered for seems like it should be a parameter, unless the process for registering for classes is radically different between classes.

If your diagram was to show a student registering for all classes then there would just be a loop over a `student.registerForClass(class)` operation.

If your diagram was to show the internal execution of the `allClassesRegistration(studentId)` operation, then you might show a diagram with a loop over something like `classRegister.register(studentID, Class)`.

If it was to specifically show a student registering for a history class, its really a scenario in which the `student.registerForClass(class)` is called with `class = history`.  You might then show more detail of what happens to the object with which the student is registering.